# Is the get property implicitly called when looking into an object during debugging?

Tags: c#, properties

I was getting some unexpected behavior of a property in one of my classes. It seems as if the get of a property is implicitly called when you look at the internals during debugging. Consider the following example:

```cs
public class ClassWithProperty
{
    public ClassWithProperty() {}

    public bool _initialFalseFlag = false;
    public bool Flag
    {
        get
        {
            _initialFalseFlag = !_initialFalseFlag;

            return _initialFalseFlag;
        }
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ClassWithProperty cls = new ClassWithProperty(); 
}
```

If I set a breakpoint at the line where `ClassWithProperty` is initialized in the Program, I see that `_initialFalseFlag` is `true`. However, the `Flag` property is never called.

It gets even weirder when I insert some print statements. If I run the following lines I get the expected output: `False, True, False`. If I however set a break point at line 2 where I print the `cls._initialFalseFlag` and then in Visual Studio expand the `cls` variable and then continue running the code I get as output `True, True, True.`

```cs
ClassWithProperty cls = new ClassWithProperty(); 
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(cls._initialFalseFlag); // Should return false
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(cls.Flag); // Should return true
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(cls.Flag); // Should return false
```

Is this expected behavior?

Comment: Having a `get` property that changes state doesn't seem like a great idea...

Comment: I guess that's what I found out the hard way.

Comment: While the answer below is correct, you can also customize how  your specific types appear within a debugger using  DebuggerTypeProxy. Your proxy could return the state of the field rather than invoking the property. Just throwing it out there so you know it exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is. Ive had trouble with it in the past as well and had luck with disabling it by going into Options>Debugging>General> 'Uncheck Enable property evaluation and other implicit function calls'. It wont show you the property value if you debug but you can at least see how it changes your code.